# How to identify a case inside statement as a fully covered case

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I need to know how do we identify a case inside statement as a fully covered case statement.
Please see the following example:

```
module test();
  logic [1:0] sel;
  initial begin
  sel = 2'b0x; // 2'b0z, 2'b0?
  $display("a is %b", sel);
  case (sel) inside
    2'b00 : $display("caseinside : 2'b00");
    2'b01 : $display("caseinside : 2'b01");
    2'b1x : $display("caseinside : 2'b1x");
    // 2'bxx : $display("caseinside : 2'bxx");
    default : $display("caseinside : default");
   endcase

   casex (sel)
     2'b00 : $display("casex : 2'b00");
     2'b01 : $display("casex : 2'b01");
     2'b1x : $display("casex : 2'b1x"); // 2'b1x => 2'b10, 2'b11
     default : $display("casex : default");
   endcase
   end
endmodule
```

Here we have both case inside and casex statements. And, the case selector is a four-state variable.
We already know this casex statement is a fully covered one since it covers all 2'b00, 2'b01 and 2'b1x (2'b10, 2'b11) case labels wrt the case selector.

But, the case inside statement is not like a fully covered one. Because, the case inside statement will reach its default case item for the given selector value ‘2'b0x’. (simulation)

According to the system verilog LRM and a couple of experiments, we can express the behavior of the case inside statements as below. (need to know whether it is correct)

- If the type of the case selector is a four-state one and it contains
  ‘x’ (or ‘z’ or ‘?’) values in its bit string, then matching case
  labels must have ‘x’ values in corresponding positions. (also other
  bits should be matched necessarily)

  Eg: let’s say the selector value is `3’b01x` then the matching case
  labels will be `3’b01x`, `3’b0xx`, `3’bx1x`, `3’bxxx`.

  As per this, case selector can have ‘3’bxxx’ and then the case inside statement must have the ‘3’bxxx’ label to be that statement is
  a fully covered one. And, if that case inside statement has the
  ‘3’bxxx’ label, then it can match any 3-bit value that passing
  through the case selector.

After these experiments we built the following algorithm to detect whether a case inside statement is a full covered one or not:

[Algo]: (we are considering the corresponding bit strings here)

- If the type of the selector variable/expression is a four-state one,

  then, there must be a case label whose width is matching to the case selector’s width and it should consist of ‘x’ (or ‘z’ or ‘?’) only. This kind of case inside statements will be identified as fully covered statements, otherwise it’s not.

  (if the label width > selector width, then the leading leading bit characters should be one of  ‘0’, ‘x’, ‘z’ or ‘?’)
- If the type of the selector variable/expression is a two-state one,

  then we can use the casex’s existing algorithm. (eg: If the width of the case selector is 2, then case inside statement should have ‘00’, ‘01’, ‘10’ and ‘11’ labels (‘x’, ‘z’, ‘?’ will be expanded to ‘0’ and ‘1’ according to the 2wild_card_count mechanism))

Please let me know if this algorithm is suitable or should I go ahead with another method (kindly suggest your algo).

[* Note: 'default' clause should not be in fully covered statements. the intention of being a fully covered case is to cut off the 'default' clause *]

Comment: what does 'fully-covered' mean in your case? BTW, module 'test' can not be compiled. You are missing a procedural block in your example. Does your case statement has to be synthesizable?

Comment: 'fully-covered' mean: for any possible value that can be provided by the case selector, there should be a matching case label except the 'default' label.
(i think 'module 'test' can not be compiled. You are missing a procedural block in your example' will depend on the platform. anyway, please consider only the case-inside & casex statements.)

Comment: in this case a label which contains all 'x' behaves the same way as the 'default' clause. So, what is the point then? I guess, you should not concider it in your algorithm if you do not concider default. Also, what do you do with 'unique/priority' stuff? It kind of suggests that the case statement is fully cover because no uncovered values can ever be in 'sel'. Also fully covered does not mean that it behaves correctly. There will be differences between differenct case types. Also there are differences between case/x/z.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine you are creating a compiler linter or something like this.

I suppose that you have width small enough to expand each label keep a set

```js
const din = document.getElementById('din')
const ul = document.getElementById('expansion');
function refresh(e){
  while(ul.lastChild){
    ul.removeChild(ul.lastChild);
  }
  function append(prefix){
      const li = document.createElement('li')
      li.textContent = prefix;
      ul.appendChild(li);
      
  }
  const s = din.value;
  if(!s) return;
  const expandedBits = {
    '0': ['0'],
    '1': ['1'],
    'x': ['0', '1', 'x', 'z'],
    'z': ['0', '1', 'x', 'z'],
    '?': ['0', '1', 'x', 'z'],
  };
  
  for(let i = 0; i < s.length; ++i){
    if(!expandedBits[s[i]]){
      append('Invalid character: ' + s[i]);
      return;
    }
  }
  // this function will enumerate all entries for one
  // label
  function expand(prefix, i){
    if(i >= s.length){
      append(prefix);
    }else{
      for(const b of expandedBits[s[i]]){
        expand(prefix + b, i + 1);
      }
    }
  }
  expand(s.length +"'b", 0);
}

din.addEventListener('input', refresh);
din.addEventListener('change', refresh);

refresh();
```

```html
Label <input type="text" id="din" pattern="[xz?01]*" value="11x0010?0">
<ul id="expansion"></ul>
```

Once you expand each label with this procedure you should have produced all the `4**n` possibility, does it make sense?